# Cannot Create Generator using Expressions

Tags: c#, expression, generic-type-argument

What I have:

```
public class HubGroup: HubObject
{
    public HubGroup(elnGroup group)
    {//do stuff}
}

public class elnGroup: elnObject
{
    //has properties
}
```

My requirement is when I give 2 types to a method, it will generate a function that will accept object of elnGroup as a parameter and return a new Instance of HubGroup. I tried a lot of things but I couldn't find a way that I can do it fast (these generator functions will be running several times)

I know you will say use generics but my Types are generated at runtime. All I have is the Base classes for both the Types which I can explicity declare. The code you see below is bits of pieces i have, just to give u a heads up of what I happening.

So I call it like:

```
public class ApiDataHandler
{
    //this will be called by a method to give json content for objEln
    public void SoFunny<T>(string strContent, T objHub) where T : HubObject
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(HubGroup))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strContant))
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot parse null/empty string! ---ApiDataHandler---");
            }

            var objEln = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<elnGroup>(strContant);
            GetHubObjectGenerator(objEln.GetType(), objHub.GetType());
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to create:

```
Func<object,object> generator = (input) => {var bObj = input as BObject;
                                            var aObj = new AObject(bObj);
                                            return aObj;
                                            }
```

I have done this: but it keeps saying:

InvalidOperationException: variable 'objEln' of type 'ElnHub.HubObjectModel.elnGroup' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

```
//also inside ApiData Handler class
    public Func<object, object> GetHubObjectGenerator(Type elnObjectType, Type hubObjectType)
    {
        ParameterExpression inputParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "input");
        ParameterExpression objCastedAsEln = Expression.Parameter(elnObjectType, "objEln");
        ParameterExpression objHub = Expression.Parameter(hubObjectType, "objHub");
        var cast = Expression.TypeAs(inputParam, elnObjectType);
        var assignCast = Expression.Assign(objCastedAsEln, cast);
        var constructor = hubObjectType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { elnObjectType }, null);
        var callingConstructor = Expression.New(constructor, new[] { objCastedAsEln });
        var assignNewObj = Expression.Assign(objHub, callingConstructor);
        var bodyBlock = Expression.Block(new[] { inputParam },
                assignCast,
                assignNewObj,
                objHub
            );
        var l = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(
                bodyBlock,
                inputParam
            );

        Func<object, object> HubObjectGenerator = l.Compile();

        return HubObjectGenerator;
    }
```

I have also tried this where i send generic types, but couldnt find my way. A bit lost here:

```
    public Func<T,T1> GetHubObjectGenerator<T,T1>() where T : elnObject where T1 : HubObject
    {
        ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "objEln");
        var constructor = typeof(T1).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,null,new[] { typeof(T) },null);
        Func<T, T1> HubObjectGenerator = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T1>>(
                Expression.New(constructor, new[] { argParam, }),
                argParam
            ).Compile();

        return HubObjectGenerator;
    }
```

Comment: You've got 3 `ParameterExpressions`, but only one actual parameter

Comment: @canton7 tried, same issue

Comment: It helps if you say *what* you tried. I pointed out something that was wrong, I didn't suggest how to fix it

Comment: @SunainaDG *what* did you try? Note: do you actually *need* the locals, for other work that isn't shown? basically, there's two ways of working with expression trees; the simple mode is: make sure everything is a simple expression, i.e. `input => new AObject(input as BObject)` - trivial to write as an `Expression<>`. There *is* a second way - you can represent full method bodies with locals etc in expression trees, but: *that is much much harder*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to write something like:

```
Func<object,object> generator = (input) =>
{
    return new AObject((BObject)input);
}
```

You need something like:

```
public Func<object, object> GetHubObjectGenerator(Type elnObjectType, Type hubObjectType)
{
    var inputParameter = ExpressionParameter(typeof(object), "input");
    var castInput = Expression.Convert(inputParameter, elnObjectType);
    var constructor = hubObjectType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { elnObjectType }, null);
    var instantiation = Expression.New(constructor, castInput);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(instantiation, inputParameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

You can use generics here easily also, you don't even need a cast:

```
public Func<THub, TEln> GetHubObjectGenerator<THub, TEln>() where THub : HubObject, TEln : elnObject
{
    var inputParameter = ExpressionParameter(typeof(TEln), "input");
    var constructor = typeof(THub).GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { typeof(TEln) }, null);
    var instantiation = Expression.New(constructor, inputParameter);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<THub, TEln>>(instantiation, inputParameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

---

I didn't use variables or `Expression.Block` here, as there's no need. If you did want to create intermediate variables, use `Expression.Variable` (`Expression.Parameter` is for input parameters only). Something like:

```
public Func<object, object> GetHubObjectGenerator(Type elnObjectType, Type hubObjectType)
{
    var inputParameter = ExpressionParameter(typeof(object), "input");

    var castInputVar = Expression.Variable(elnObjectType, "eln");
    var castInput = Expression.Convert(inputParameter, elnObjectType);
    var castInputAssign = Expression.Assign(castInputVar, castInput);

    var constructor = hubObjectType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new[] { elnObjectType }, null);
    var hubObjectVar = Expression.Variable(hubObjectType, "hub");
    var instantiation = Expression.New(constructor, castInputVar);
    var hubObjectAssign = Expression.Assign(hubObjectVar, instantiation);

    var block = Expression.Block(new[] { castInputVar, hubObjectVar },
        castInputAssign,
        hubObjectAssign,
        hubObject);

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(block, inputParameter);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

Comment: You saved my day!!! But where was I going wrong. I did pretty much the same thing except assigning to variables..

Comment: I haven't been through yours in much detail, but 1) you declared 3 parameters but only one was an actual parameter, 2) Even if they had been declared as variables, they weren't being passed to `Expression.Block` 3) you passed the actual input parameter to `Expression.Block`

Comment: Btw when I call the generated method it says: not set to an instance of an object

Comment: What line of code *exactly* throws that exception? Unfortunately my psychic debugger is broken at the moment

Comment: var gen = GetHubObjectGenerator(objEln.GetType(), objHub.GetType());

                var a = gen(objEln); <<<<<<---- here

Comment: Then debug it and see why `gen` is null

Comment: gen is not null, its returning Func<object,object>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216271/discussion-between-sunainadg-and-canton7).